# Angular.JS ng-repeat breaking apart a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to Angular.JS and trying to figure out how to properly implement ng-repeat.

I have a data object in my scope that was formed from JSON from my database. One of the returned 'fields' can sometimes either be just a single string, or an array.

Example:

```
Email Address = "me@test.com" or
Email Address = ["me1@test.com", "me2@test.com", "me3@test.com"]
```

I would simply like to display in a series of spans whatever Email Address would contain.  So far, I've done this:

```
<span ng-repeat="EMAIL_ADDRESS in data.EMAIL_ADDRESS">
    <span>{{EMAIL_ADDRESS}}</span><br />
</span
```

For the Email Address that's an array of 3, I get this (which I want):

```
    <span>me1@test.com</span><br />
    <span>me2@test.com</span><br />
    <span>me3@test.com</span><br />
```

For the Email Address that's just a string I get:

```
    <span>m</span><br />
    <span>e</span><br />
    <span>@</span><br />
    <span>t</span><br />
    <span>e</span><br />
    <span>s</span><br />
    <span>t</span><br />
    <span>.</span><br />
    <span>c</span><br />
    <span>o</span><br />
    <span>m</span><br />
```

How can I prevent the later situation?  I know this is more Javascript behavior, but I'm not sure how to put it in Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can't change the returned object from the database, or if you have do do this on multiple variables, you could implement a function to transform the string into an array, which will prevent your ng-repeat to parse it

One possible function could be implemented directly in your controller :

```
$scope.formatData=function(objectFromDB){
    if(!angular.isArray(objectFromDB))
       return [objectFromDB];
    else
       return objectFromDB;
    }
```

Then you just have to call the function with your data

```
<span ng-repeat="EMAIL_ADDRESS in formatData(data.EMAIL_ADDRESS)">
```

Comment: Easy to implement, and works like a charm.  I feel that this answer was the best giving it's portability and clean approach. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The angular way would be to format your data after you receive it. If the value is a string replace it with an array containing that value. This way your template will receive a consistent result and your controller logic will deal with consistent data structures.

**Edit**: I would also not bind the raw return data from the server to the $scope directly. I like to add a level of separation between the data names/types of the server and of the client to ensure future ease of change and no strong coupling.

**JS**:

```
$http.get('/my/data').success(function(data) {
  //here's where I'd do all the data transformation and binding
  if(angular.isArray(data.EMAIL_ADDRESS)) {
    $scope.emailAddresses = data.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
  else {
    $scope.emailAddresses = [data.EMAIL_ADDRESS];
  }
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<span ng-repeat="emailAddress in emailAddresses">
```

This way your templates are not bound to the server api return values/properties

Answer (score 0):

You can have separate spans/docs to show different cases: with ngRepeat for arrays and without it for simple string.

So kind of

```
<div ng-show="isString(data.EMAIL_ADDRESS)">{{data.EMAIL_ADDRESS}}<div><div ng-hide="isString(data.EMAIL_ADDRESS)" ng-repeat="address in data.EMAIL_ADDRESS">{{address}}<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch your data from server:

```
EMAIL_ADDRESS = EMAIL_ADDRESS instanceof Array ? EMAIL_ADDRESS : [EMAIL_ADDRESS]
```